# How to listen to slack messages using clojure?

Tags: clojure, slack, slack-api

I am using [clj-slack](https://github.com/julienXX/clj-slack) start method for getting the web-socket url and then passing it to the connect method of [gniazdo](https://clojars.org/stylefruits/gniazdo) for listening to the web-socket.

```
(require '[clj-slack.rtm :as slack])
(require '[gniazdo.core :as ws])

(def connection {:api-url "https://slack.com/api" :token "your token"})

(defn reset-conn [options]
(def socket
  (ws/connect
    (:url (slack/start options))
    :on-receive #(prn 'received %))))
(reset-conn connection)
```

This code is working fine but it only provides information about who is active or away for slack:

```
received"{\"type\":\"presence_change\",\"presence\":\"active\",\"user\":\"U7BCQHWHY\"}"
```

But I also want to listen to the messages.

I don't know why messages are not printed though it was stated in slack-api [documentation](https://api.slack.com/methods/) that rtm(`real time messaging`) is for messaging session.

Comment: Works for me. `"RECEIVED" ("{\"type\":\"hello\"}") "RECEIVED"
("{\"type\":\"reconnect_url\",\"url\":\"...\"}") "RECEIVED"
("{\"type\":\"reconnect_url\",\"url\":\"...\"}") "RECEIVED"
("{\"type\":\"presence_change\",\"presence\":\"away\",\"user\":\"U49SAFE21\"}") "RECEIVED" ("{\"type\":\"message\",\"channel\":\"D5ES9KCTY\",\"user\":\"U5DFFHS2V\",\"text\":\"that\",\"ts\":\"1507121468.000227\",\"source_team\":\"T0D48JNUT\",\"team\":\"T0D48JNUT\"}") "RECEIVED" ("{\"type\":\"presence_change\",\"presence\":\"away\",\"user\":\"U0D48LASF\"}")`

Comment: yup it is works. Earlier i wasn't added to any channel. So..., thanks anyway.